# Continuous functions are bounded on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Prove that a continuous function $ f : D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded when $D \subseteq \mathbb R$ is compact.

Seeking a contradiction, first assume there exists a sequence $x_i \in D$ such that as $i \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x_i) \rightarrow \infty$. Since $x_i \in D$ and $D$ is compact, $x_i$ must converge to a finite limit $x^* \in D$. Since $f$ is continuous, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a neighborhood of $x^*$, $U$, such that for all $x \in U$ we have that $|f(x) - f(x^*)| < \epsilon$. But this is a contradiction since $f(x_i)$ is arbitrarily large as $x_i \rightarrow x^*$. So $f$ must be bounded on $D$.

**My question**

Is it sufficient to show that no such sequence can exist (as I've done above)? I think that should be sufficient since if $f$ is unbounded, then I can define a sequence such that $f(x_i) \rightarrow \infty$. The proof is by contrapositive.

Comment: Why must $x_i$ converge?

Comment: I had meant $D \subseteq \mathbb R$

Comment: @dmh , spaceisdarkgreen's question is an important one. You need to show why such convergent sequence exists. For general sequence, you're only ensured there is a convergent subsequence but we don't know the limit of that convergent sequence is $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a real-valued function with real domain.

We say that $f$ is continuous iff its maps convergent sequences into convergent sequences.

In $\mathbb{R}$, we can define compactness in terms of convergence of sequences.

More precisely, one says that $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact if every sequence admits a convergent subsequence.

Based on such considerations, it can be claimed that $f(D)$ is compact once $D$ is compact.

Now it remains to prove compactness implies boundedness.

In order to do so, it is interesting to remember its definition:
\begin{align*}
X\subset\mathbb{R}\ \text{is bounded} \Longleftrightarrow (\exists c\in\mathbb{R})(\forall x\in X)(x\leq c)
\end{align*}

Consequently, its negation can be phrased as follows:
\begin{align*}
X\subset\mathbb{R} \ \text{is not bounded} \Longleftrightarrow (\forall c\in\mathbb{R})(\exists x\in X)(x > c)
\end{align*}

Having said that, we may claim for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there corresponds some $x_{n}\in X$ such that $x_{n} > n$.

Such sequence, by its turn, admits a convergent subsequence $x_{f(n)}$, which is bounded.

This means there exists some natural number $N$ such that $x_{f(n)} < N$ for every value of $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We can then choose $n = N$. Hence we conclude that $f(N) < x_{f(N)} < N$, which is a contradiction.

Indeed, $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function so that $f(N) \geq N$.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: How is $x_{f(n)}$ defined?

Comment: The corresponding function represents the index of the subsequence such that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is strictly increasing. Its expression may vary in accordance to the target subsequence of interest.